# how to pass values to controller through ajax in mvc 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Please find Image.
I have written AJAX call on drop down menu's change event and upon selecting required fields ,I want to pass selected fields to controller on Submit button click through another AJAX call. Here is my code. Is it possible to do so. I'm new bee ,if more information needed please comment.

```js
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlUser").change(function () {
            var User = $("#ddlUser option:selected").val();
            if (User != "") {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/GetPermissionDatail",
                    data: '{Username: "' + $("#ddlUser :selected").val().toString() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            var trHTML = '';
                            var cnt = 1;
                            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                                if (item.Status == "True") {
                                    trHTML += '<tr><td style=display:none;>' + item.PermID + '</td><td>' + item.Fname + '</td><td style=display:none;>' + item.formlinkname + '</td><td style=display:none;>' + item.Status + '</td><td><input id=Checkbox' + cnt + ' value=' + item.PermID + ',' + item.Fname + ' type=checkbox checked> </td></tr>';

                                }
                                else {
                                    trHTML += '<tr><td style=display:none;>' + item.PermID + '</td><td>' + item.Fname + '</td><td style=display:none;>' + item.formlinkname + '</td><td style=display:none;>' + item.Status + '</td><td><input id=Checkbox' + cnt + '  value=' + item.PermID + ',' + item.Fname + ' type=checkbox></td></tr>';
                                }
                                cnt++;
                            });
                            $('#records_table tbody').empty();
                            $('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML);

                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Error" + response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var favorite = [];
        var chkuser;
        $("#ddlUser").change(function (){
            chkuser = $("#ddlUser :selected").val();
        });
        $("#Submit1").click(function (){
            //alert(getvalue_func());
            favorite.push(getvalue_func());
            var favString = favorite.join();
            alert(chkuser+","+favString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/SetPermissionsuser",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Username: "' + chkuser.toString() + '" }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
        function getvalue_func() {
            return $('#records_table input:checked').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(', ');
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9 push-md-3 panel-warning" >
 <div class="content-box-header panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title ">Permission</div>
   <div class="panel-options">
    <a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
    <a href="#" data-rel="reload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-large box-with-header" style="font-family:Century Gothic;font-weight:bolder;font-size:12px">

                <div class="user-dashboard" id="Userwidth">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="sales">
                                    <h2>Select User :</h2>
                                    <div class="btn">
                                            <select class="form-control" id="ddlUser" style="width:200px;">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                                {
                                                    <option>@item.UserName</option>
                                                }
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="user-dashboard">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 gutter">
                                <div class="sales nav navbar-nav">
                                    <h5>Select form which you want to give permission</h5>
                                        <table class="table" id="records_table">
                                            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row" style="display:none;">ID</th>
                                                <th>Form Name</th>
                                                <th style="display:none;">Form Link Name</th>
                                            </tr> 
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                    
                                            </tbody>                               
                                        </table>    
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="user-dashboard">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="sales">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 "><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" /></div> 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div> 
            }
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass to `data` an object :

```
$.ajax(
  {
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Home/GetPermissionDatail",
     data: {Username: $("#ddlUser:selected").val()},
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     ...
```

Comment: could you explain in details ..?

Comment: in your code you pass string to 'data' : '{Username: "' + $("#ddlUser :selected").val().toString() + '" }' . you need to pass an object : data: {Username: $("#ddlUser:selected").val()}

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this will helpful for you

when you create checkbox give class to checkbox.

```
<input class="Checkbox" id=Checkbox' + cnt + '  value=' + item.PermID + ',' + item.Fname + ' type=checkbox>
```

hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidObjects" name="hidObjects" value="0" />



 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           var chkuser;
            $("#ddlUser").change(function (){
                chkuser = $("#ddlUser :selected").val();
            });
            $("#Submit1").click(function (){
                var SelectedIds = GetSelectCheckboxId();
                $('#hidObjects').val(SelectedIds);
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/SetPermissionsuser",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ Username: "' + chkuser.toString() + '" }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
 function GetSelectCheckboxId() {
        var value = "";
        $(".checkbox:checked").each(function () {
            if (value == "")
                    value = $(this).val();
                else
                    value += "," + $(this).val();
           });
        return value;
    }
    </script>
```

on controller

```
   [HttpPost]
 public string YourActionName(FormCollection pFormObj)
 {
     string[] arr = pFormObj["hidObjects"].Split(',');
 }
```